# Molest and molestation

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

I was watching an advertisment. In that, they highlighted the following:

"molest is a crime".

Or should it be "molestation is a crime"?

Comment: Yes.  "Molest" is the verb, "molestation" the noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. And, for writers, know that "molestation" doesn't always mean what you think it means; in some jurisdictions it is defined as just acting creepy and hanging around kids and pestering them or engaging in weird conversation or inviting them places.
So when you are writing about child molesters, make sure that you keep that difference in mind. Could save you from a libel suit or worse.